# Silverlight custom xmllanguage

Tags: silverlight, localization

I'm trying to localize my SL 4 application.

In order  to localize the SL controls, I have to use:

```
this.Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name);
```

The problem is I'm using custom cultures to override decimal separator and date format.

The XmlLanguage.GetLanguage function creates a culture based on the IETF language tag.

So my question is: how to pass my custom parameters to the XmlLanguage?

Thx a lot